# Firefox addon : Access to storage in the popup

Tags: javascript, popup, firefox-addon

I would like to access to the storage from a script loaded via the  popup HTML of the toolbar button.

Like that : `browser.storage.local.get(key)`

The problem is that the `browser` object is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad, the `browser` object is defined even in the popup. The "undefined error" was fired when I tried to run my code outside of the popup.